# How to make new players spawn EXACTLY on one block, not anywhere around it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm honestly clueless as to what to do. I've tried this:

> /gamerule spawnRadius 0

But it has no affect. When I do /kill, I always spawn around 10 blocks away from where I'd like to spawn. It's important that the player spawns there, because it
immediately triggers a pressure plate that makes "Welcome!" pop up on the screen in rainbow colors. It's also a parkour map, with lots of checkpoints, so making sure the spawn point is correct is crucial to the success of this creation.

Using Minecraft 1.12.2

Comment: That does indeed work for me. Are using vanilla? If not, you should list what sort of mods or plugins you're using.

Comment: Firstly, you can just use `/spawnpoint` for all players. Secondly, the gamerule works for me. Can you try to reproduce it? Create a new world, enter `/gamerule spawnRadius 0`, kill yourself a few times and see if you appear on the same block. If it works, try to find the difference between the two worlds that make it not work by narrowing down the cause.

Comment: @Skylinerw I'm using vanilla. I have no plugins or mods installed, because this is going to be a singleplayer adventure map. I've been using command blocks with everything so far.

Comment: [Here is the wiki on spawning](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn#Player_spawning).  The section on player spawning is worth a read as it covers all the aspects that need to be understood.  If you use `/setworldspawn` and `/gamerule spawnRadius 0`, this should set the spawn where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

I did `/spawnpoint @a` then, `/setworldspawn` and then, `/gamerule spawnRadius`

I did everything together because I needed it to work.

Comment: But: did it work?

Answer (score 0):

If just setting the "worldspawnpoint" command does not work then you can make a box where the players spawn with trip wires that hook up to a command block with following command in it.

In a normal and always active command block enter the following command:`/tp @p ~(coordinate 1) ~(coordinate 2) ~(coordinate 3)`

Answer (score -1):

To make sure to make players spawn on a specific block in Minecraft 1.12.2 you must type in the command: /set world spawn point (quadrants). If this doesn't work then frankly, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: This answer doesn't help at all. What do you mean with "/set world spawn point (quadrants)"? Why did you put spaces into the command name? And it's not even the correct command name.

Comment: @Emily Teaniy I'm not really command-savvy, but even I know that isn't a command in minecraft. I tried it anyway, but it didn't work.

Comment: [Here is the wiki on the setworldspawn command](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#setworldspawn) but this command only sets the world spawn point.  It has nothing to do with limiting the random spawn around this spawn point.  Also, you said "If this doesn't work...", if you are unsure if it will work, it is not an answer.

Comment: The OP is clearly experiencing bugs, so it's totally natural for @EmilyTeaniy to be unsure if their answer will work.  Also being unsure doesn't necessarily keep something from being a good answer.

Comment: Also I googled the command and it is definitely a real command.  https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/setworldspawn